# Fastest way traversing a graph with several unknown weight edges

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, graph-traversal

Given a undirected and positive weighted graph **G**, some edges of **G** have unknown weight. For instance,

[image]

where **edge(B, C)** has unknown weight.

Traversing from **A** to **B** costs you **7**.
We are allowed to derive the unknown weight **e = weight(B,C)** by traversing from **B** to **C** or vise versa and costs you **e**, which becomes a known weight in the end. And walk from **A** to **C** through **B** costs you **e+7** in total.

My question is, **how fast can we get all the unknown weight when given a starting point?** That is, traverse all the unknown weight edges from a starting point(e.g **A**) with as small costs as possible.

The case that the number of unknown weight is **1** is simple. You can first find out the shortest path from the starting point to the vertices of the desired edge and traverse the unknown weight edge. However, I don't know how to solve it when the number of unknown weight edges grows larger than 1.

Can anyone figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Can't offer a complete solution, but it looks related to the travelling salesman problem where the unknown edges are the nodes to be visited.

But I think you can't find an optimal solution a priori. Consider this example

```
a-b = 1
b-c = ?
b-d = ?
a-d = 10
```

if `b-c` has low weight (say 1) the shortest path starting from `a` is `a-b-c-b-d` which traverses `b-c` twice. If `b-c` has high weight (say 100) the shortest path becomes `a-d-b-c`, preferring the cheaper connection `a-d` over traversing `b-c` twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a second graph, `G'`, which will be the same - but without the "unkown edges"<sup>1</sup>. Then, you can use all to all shortest path algorithm, and use the data from the algorithm to fill in the blanks.

[Floyd Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) offers an `O(n3)` all to all shortest path.

---

(1) Formally: `G'=(V,E',w')` where:

`E' = { e | e is in E and w(e) != ? }`

`w'(e) = w(e) if w(e) != ?`

Comment: 1 silly question here: what if the edges connected to the starting point are all unknown weight edges?

Comment: @ylc: The the graph `G'` is not connected and the "cost" will be `infinity` (or undefined) for the unknown edges. This is what we expect, since there is no other path between the two vertices, and the weight of the unknown edge is undefined.